# using createselector still rerenders component

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, reselect

I learn about redux and its features. One thing that I get trouble with is createselector in reduxtoolkit. I have a slice:

```
const titlesSlice = createSlice({
name: "title",
initialState: {
titles: [],
title: "",
},
reducers: {
addTitle: (state, action) => {
  state.titles.push({
    id: Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10000).toString(),
    title: state.title,
  });
 },
 titleChange: (state, action) => {
  state.title = action.payload;
 },
},
});
```

and a selectors like:

```
const getTitles = (state) => (state.titles.titles);

 export const selectTitlesLengthWithReselect = createSelector(
[getTitles],
(titles) => titles.filter(elem => elem.title.length > 5))
```

In App.js I added input for adding title:

```
function App(props) {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const title = useSelector((state) => state.titles.title);

return (
<div className="App">
  <div>
    <input type="text" 
    onChange={(e) => dispatch(titleChange(e.target.value))}
    value={title} />
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(addTitle())}>Save</button>
    <Titlelist />
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

TitleList component:

```
const Titlelist = () => {
const allTitles = useSelector(selectTitlesLengthWithReselect);
console.log("RENDERED");
return (
    <div>
        {allTitles.map((elem) => (
            <li key={elem.id}>{elem.title}</li>
        ))}
    </div>
)
}
```

Problem is every time input value(title in the titleReducer) changes the TitleList component rerenders. But the data that comes from selector is memoized(I checked for the prev and current value equality and they are same). Is there something that I'm doing wrong or why does component rerenders?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your selector, it is memoized, the selector did not cause the re render (re creating of jsx).

Dispatching titleChange will re render App so it will re render Titlelist because it is not a [pure component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#overview), you can make it a pure component with React.memo:

```
const Titlelist = React.memo(function TitleList() {
  const allTitles = useSelector(
    selectTitlesLengthWithReselect
  );
  console.log('RENDERED');
  return (
    <div>
      {allTitles.map((elem) => (
        <li key={elem.id}>{elem.title}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```

As phry commented; it is usually fine to let your component re create jsx as React will do a virtual DOM compare and not re render DOM if the jsx is the same, if you have handlers that are re created (like: `onClick={()=>new ref}`) then that will fail virtual DOM compare. You can use useCallback to prevent that.

A pure component will generate the same jsx reference if no props changed so will have a quicker virtual dom compare but will also take up more memory and setup processing so it may not always benefit your application.

Comment: Adding to that: generally is is also **just okay to render**. You don't have to prevent every render by every means - React is built for that. Just optimize renders where you see a measurable impact on performance.